# C fread() matrix , reading in nine bad values no matter what matrix size

Tags: c, file-io, matrix, fread

```
void matrix_writebinary(struct matrep *mat) {
 int i,j;

FILE *fptr;
if((fptr=fopen("matrixA.bin","wb"))==NULL)
{
puts("Cannot Open File");
}

fwrite(&mat->rows,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
fwrite(&mat->cols,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
fwrite(mat->matrix,sizeof(double),(mat->rows*mat->cols),fptr);

fclose(fptr);   
}
/***********************************************************/

double *matrix_readbinary(struct matrep *mat) {
int i,j;


FILE *fptr;
if((fptr=fopen("matrixA.bin","rb"))==NULL)
{
puts("Cannot Open File");
}

fread(&mat->rows,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
fread(&mat->cols,sizeof(int),1,fptr);

mat->matrix = (double *) malloc( sizeof( double ) * (mat->rows*mat->cols) ) ;
fread(mat->matrix,sizeof(double),(mat->rows*mat->cols),fptr);

fclose(fptr);  
return mat->matrix;
}
```

I am using the above two functions to write a matrix to a binary file, and then read the matrix back from the file using fread.

Then I am printing the matrix, but every time I do, the first 9 elements of the matrix are zero, no matter what size mat.rows or mat.cols are, always 9 empty elements or -1.#R when trying to print, so I think that
    fread(val,sizeof(double),(mat->rows*mat->cols),fptr);

is reading in 9 bad doubles but I have no idea why...

In the main(), the user specifies the row and col size etc.

If someone could explain why I would really appreciate it.

Here is the func used to print

```
void print_matrix( struct matrep *mat ) 
{
double *ptr ;
int i, j ;

ptr=mat->matrix;

if ( mat->matrix==0 || mat->rows==0 || mat->cols==0 )
   {
   printf("\n\nEmpty matrix" );
   return ;       
   }

printf( "\n\nrows %d, columns %d\n\n",  mat->rows,  mat->cols) ;
for ( i=0; i <  mat->rows; i++ )
    {
    for ( j=0; j <  mat->cols; j++ )
        {
        printf( "%5.2lf\t", *ptr++ );
        }
    printf( "\n" ) ;
}

}
```

and the structure used...

```
struct matrep {
  int rows,cols;
  double *matrix;
};
struct matrep MATRIX,MATRIX1;
```

code that call matrix_readbinary() in main()

```
//BINARY WRITE/READ
printf("\nWriting binary data now...\n");
matrix_writebinary( &MATRIX ) ; 
_flushall();
getchar();
printf("\nReading binary data now...\n");
MATRIX1.matrix=matrix_readbinary(&MATRIX1 ) ; // reads above matrix from file as a copy 
if(MATRIX1.matrix!=NULL){
                        printf("\nPrinting read .bin...\n");
                        print_matrix(&MATRIX1 ) ; // prints this copyed matrix
                         }
```

Comment: show the code that calls matrix_readbinary

Comment: The code you have posted looks like it should work. That would indicate the problem is in creating the original double array. Try printing the original matrix and see what you get.

Comment: its a single array with row and col info when printing, I have no issues printing the original matrix to the screen, neither is there a problem when writing and then reading from a text file and printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test app under Windows with Visual Studio using your posted code and it worked fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct matrep
{
  int rows,cols;
  double *matrix;
};

void matrix_writebinary(struct matrep *mat)
{
  int i,j;
  FILE *fptr;
  if((fptr=fopen("matrixA.bin","wb"))==NULL)
  {
    puts("Cannot Open File");
  }
  fwrite(&mat->rows,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
  fwrite(&mat->cols,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
  fwrite(mat->matrix,sizeof(double),(mat->rows*mat->cols),fptr);
  fclose(fptr);
}

/***********************************************************/
double *matrix_readbinary(struct matrep *mat)
{
  int i,j;
  FILE *fptr;
  if((fptr=fopen("matrixA.bin","rb"))==NULL)
  {
    puts("Cannot Open File");
  }
  fread(&mat->rows,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
  fread(&mat->cols,sizeof(int),1,fptr);
  mat->matrix = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(mat->rows*mat->cols));
  fread(mat->matrix,sizeof(double),(mat->rows*mat->cols),fptr);
  fclose(fptr);
  return mat->matrix;
} 

void print_matrix( struct matrep *mat )
{
  double *ptr ;
  int i, j ;
  ptr=mat->matrix;
  if ( mat->matrix==0 || mat->rows==0 || mat->cols==0 )
  {
    printf("\n\nEmpty matrix" );
    return ;
  }
  printf( "\n\nrows %d, columns %d\n\n",  mat->rows,  mat->cols) ;
  for ( i=0; i <  mat->rows; i++ )
  {
    for ( j=0; j <  mat->cols; j++ )
    {
      printf( "%5.2lf\t", *ptr++ );
    }
    printf( "\n" ) ;
  }
}

struct matrep MATRIX,MATRIX1;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int  r;
  int c;
  double*  pdbl;

  MATRIX.rows = 4;
  MATRIX.cols = 3;
  pdbl = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * MATRIX.rows * MATRIX.cols);
  MATRIX.matrix = pdbl;
  for ( r = 0; r < MATRIX.rows; ++r )
  {
    for ( c = 0; c < MATRIX.cols; ++c )
    {
      *pdbl++ = c + r;
    }
  }
  matrix_writebinary(&MATRIX);
  print_matrix(&MATRIX);
  matrix_readbinary(&MATRIX1);
  print_matrix(&MATRIX1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double *val=mat->matrix;
...
val = (double *) malloc( sizeof( double ) * (mat->rows*mat->cols) ) ;
fread(val,sizeof(double),(mat->rows*mat->cols),fptr);
```

You initially set `val` to `mat->matrix` (junk, I presume), and then reset it to the return value of `malloc()`.  You never actually set `mat->matrix` to anything.

Comment: if I change it so that I set *val=mat->matrix; and then malloc the mat->matrix the same thing happens, should that or not fix it?

Comment: After the `fread(val,...)`, you should set `mat->matrix = val;`.

Comment: @user1085611: You need to assign the result of `malloc` to `mat->matrix`, not to `val`.

Comment: @user1085611: Get rid of `val`, it is an unnecessary variable. Just use `mat->matrix` everywhere instead.

Comment: @dreamlax have gotten rid of val, however the results remain the same